# Cryptography install hangs on Amazon AMI when running `./certbot-auto --debug --verbose certonly --standalone -d foo.com`

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, cryptography, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install Certbot and genereate some certificates for my Amazon AMI server, however when I run:

```
sudo ./certbot-auto --debug --verbose certonly --standalone -d foo.com
```

the setup hangs when it gets to:

```
...

Running setup.py install for cryptography ... \
```

I have tried to install cryptography separately but it does the same thing, it just hang at the same line.

Full log:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-137 tmp]$ sudo ./certbot-auto --debug --verbose certonly --standalone -d foo.com
Bootstrapping dependencies via Amazon Linux...
yum is /usr/bin/yum
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                        | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                     | 2.3 kB     00:00     
Package gcc-4.8.3-3.20.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Package augeas-libs-1.0.0-5.7.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:openssl-1.0.1k-15.99.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1k-15.99.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libffi-devel-3.0.13-16.5.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package system-rpm-config-9.0.3-42.28.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Package ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.16.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Package python27-2.7.12-2.120.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python27-devel-2.7.12-2.120.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python27-virtualenv-12.0.7-1.13.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Package python27-tools-2.7.12-2.120.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python27-pip-6.1.1-1.23.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
Creating virtual environment...
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Installing Python packages...
Collecting argparse==1.4.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 11))
  Downloading argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser==2.14 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 17))
  Downloading pycparser-2.14.tar.gz (223kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 10.3MB/s 
Collecting cffi==1.4.2 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 21))
  Downloading cffi-1.4.2.tar.gz (365kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 368kB 12.7MB/s 
Collecting ConfigArgParse==0.10.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 38))
  Downloading ConfigArgParse-0.10.0.tar.gz
Collecting configobj==5.0.6 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 40))
  Downloading configobj-5.0.6.tar.gz
Collecting cryptography==1.5.3 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 42))
  Downloading cryptography-1.5.3.tar.gz (400kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 401kB 12.7MB/s 
Collecting enum34==1.1.2 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 65))
  Downloading enum34-1.1.2.tar.gz (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 49kB 15.9MB/s 
Collecting funcsigs==0.4 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 68))
  Downloading funcsigs-0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna==2.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 71))
  Downloading idna-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 13.3MB/s 
Collecting ipaddress==1.0.16 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 74))
  Downloading ipaddress-1.0.16-py27-none-any.whl
Collecting linecache2==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 77))
  Downloading linecache2-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ordereddict==1.1 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 80))
  Downloading ordereddict-1.1.tar.gz
Collecting parsedatetime==2.1 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 82))
  Downloading parsedatetime-2.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting pbr==1.8.1 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 85))
  Downloading pbr-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 90kB 18.4MB/s 
Collecting pyasn1==0.1.9 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 88))
  Downloading pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyOpenSSL==16.2.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 100))
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-16.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 45kB 13.7MB/s 
Collecting pyparsing==2.1.8 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 103))
  Downloading pyparsing-2.1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 57kB 21.9MB/s 
Collecting pyRFC3339==1.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 112))
  Downloading pyRFC3339-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-augeas==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 115))
  Downloading python-augeas-0.5.0.tar.gz (90kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 94kB 16.2MB/s 
Collecting pytz==2015.7 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 117))
  Downloading pytz-2015.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (476kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 479kB 17.9MB/s 
Collecting requests==2.12.1 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 131))
  Downloading requests-2.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (574kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 577kB 18.4MB/s 
Collecting six==1.10.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 134))
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting traceback2==1.4.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 137))
  Downloading traceback2-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting unittest2==1.1.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 140))
  Downloading unittest2-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (96kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 98kB 24.6MB/s 
Collecting zope.component==4.2.2 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 143))
  Downloading zope.component-4.2.2.tar.gz (546kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 548kB 23.7MB/s 
Collecting zope.event==4.1.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 145))
  Downloading zope.event-4.1.0.tar.gz (476kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 479kB 23.6MB/s 
Collecting zope.interface==4.1.3 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 147))
  Downloading zope.interface-4.1.3.tar.gz (141kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 23.8MB/s 
Collecting mock==1.0.1 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 165))
  Downloading mock-1.0.1.zip (861kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 864kB 25.0MB/s 
Collecting letsencrypt==0.7.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 168))
  Downloading letsencrypt-0.7.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting acme==0.12.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 174))
  Downloading acme-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (95kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 98kB 25.3MB/s 
Collecting certbot==0.12.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 177))
  Downloading certbot-0.12.0-py2-none-any.whl (238kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 241kB 25.9MB/s 
Collecting certbot-apache==0.12.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 180))
  Downloading certbot_apache-0.12.0-py2-none-any.whl (124kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 126kB 25.7MB/s 
Collecting certbot-nginx==0.12.0 (from -r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 183))
  Downloading certbot_nginx-0.12.0-py2-none-any.whl (61kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 24.4MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=11.3 in /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography==1.5.3->-r /tmp/tmp.YzC6SBROHr/letsencrypt-auto-requirements.txt (line 42))
Installing collected packages: argparse, pycparser, cffi, ConfigArgParse, six, configobj, idna, pyasn1, enum34, ipaddress, cryptography, funcsigs, linecache2, ordereddict, parsedatetime, pbr, pyOpenSSL, pyparsing, pytz, pyRFC3339, python-augeas, requests, traceback2, unittest2, zope.interface, zope.event, zope.component, mock, acme, certbot, letsencrypt, certbot-apache, certbot-nginx
  Running setup.py install for pycparser ... done
  Running setup.py install for cffi ... done
  Running setup.py install for ConfigArgParse ... done
  Running setup.py install for configobj ... done
  Running setup.py install for enum34 ... done
  Running setup.py install for cryptography ... \
```

Comment: What does it print if you install it manually via `pip -v`?

Comment: same thing: `Running setup.py install for cryptography ... \ ` - and hangs there. :(